# Uniform planar graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

What's the name of a planar graph in which every (inner) face has the same number $k$ of vertices? Something like $k$-uniform planar graph?

And is there a name for planar graphs in which every face has at most $k$ vertices?

Comment: Thanks, Kuba, I looked for such a tag but didn't find it.

Answer (score 5):

If $k=3$ you call the graph a *triangulation*. If $k=4$ it is called *quadrangulation*. I am not aware of any other terms for a fixed $k>4$.

For a non-fixed $k$ you might say *graphs with face-degree $k$*. Or *duals of $k$-regular graphs*. How about *$k$-gonalization*?

Comment: Is it still called a triangulation if the outside face isn't a triangle?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Well this depends. If you are coming lets say from the graph drawing or meshing community then you would probably still call it a triangulation. On the other hand, if your background is more on polytopes and graph theory then rather not.